# how to detect user read message with telethon?

Tags: python, api, telegram, telethon

I send message to a user with Telethon (python wrapper for telegram API).
Now I want to know users that received my message read that or not.
Same as two tick in Telegram clients when user read message.

Comment: how can use flags parameter in this link with telethon: https://core.telegram.org/constructor/message

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`MessageRead`](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telethon.events.html#telethon.events.messageread.MessageRead) event. It is triggered when a user reads a message you sent.

Comment: ok thanks, but some time service is down when read event occured. is there any method to check a known message in known chat is read or not?

Comment: Get the dialogs, they have a field that tells you the message ID up to which the user has read.