# How to detect if my messages on telegram is already read using telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I sent multiple messages to my contacts on telegram using telethon but I didn't use this events to know if they are read directly so I want to check if my messages are read or not using other method

```
@client.on(events.MessageRead)
async def handler(event):
    # Log when someone reads your messages
    print('Someone has read all your messages until', event.max_id)
```

I read the full documentation and I can't find an answer is there anyway to know if the message is read or not using its id as example? cz even when I called get_dialogs() function it gives me the ID of last message and not the last read message by user as the comment given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53145602/9218774)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the `Dialog` where you sent the `message` using [`GetPeerDialogsRequest()`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/get_peer_dialogs.html), then if the `read_outbox_max_id` property is equal or higher than the `message.id`, the message has been read.

```
chat = 'INSERT_CHAT'
msg_id = (await client.send_message(chat, 'YOUR_TEXT')).id

# get the Dialog where you sent the message
result = await client(functions.messages.GetPeerDialogsRequest(
        peers=[chat]
    ))
# check if the message has been read    
if result.dialogs[0].read_outbox_max_id >= msg_id:
    print('the message has been read')
else:
    print('the message has not been read yet')
```

Comment: thank you, GetPeerDialogsRequest() function is doing its job :)

Comment: I wonder if this works based on the call-back event. I tried it and it didn't seem to trigger when the actual read action was performed.